# Re-use incorrect printing

Tags: python, decorator

I have the following simple code (which represents much larger code):

```
def dec(data):
    def wrap_func(*args, **kwargs):
        if not wrap_func.has_run: print(
            '\n$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*___This is Start of FUNC___ \'{}\' $*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*\n'.format(
                data.__name__))

        print(data(*args, **kwargs))
        if not wrap_func.has_run: print(
            '\n$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*___This is End of FUNC___ \'{}\' $*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*\n'.format(
                data.__name__))
            wrap_func.has_run = True

        # return result

        wrap_func.has_run = False
    return wrap_func


@dec
def sum(a=1, b=1, times=1):
    return (a + b) * times

@dec
def multi(a=2, b=3):
    return sum(a, b=0, times=b)


# sum(1, 3)
multi(2,3)
```

If only the line of sum (1,3) are operating I get (as intended):

```
$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*___This is Start of FUNC___ 'sum' $*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*
4
$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*___This is End of FUNC___ 'sum' $*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*
```

If only the line of `multi (2,3)` operating I get these annoying 'leftovers' from the summing function:

```
$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*___This is Start of FUNC___ 'multi' $*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*
$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*___This is Start of FUNC___ 'sum' $*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*
6
$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*___This is End of FUNC___ 'sum' $*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*
None
$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*___This is End of FUNC___ 'multi' $*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*
```

So the issue is, if I use a decorator which uses a function/method which has also the same decorator, it prints me the useless data of the internal function

What I wish to see is:

```
$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*___This is Start of FUNC___ 'multi' $*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*

6

$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*___This is End of FUNC___ 'multi' $*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*$*
```

Comment: The indentation of `dec` was clearly wrong. Please verify that my attempt to correct it reflects your actual code.

Comment: If you decorate the function you lose the undecorated form. And you can't trivially tell which you should be calling either.

Comment: @Danny Kaminski, Try to keep the question simple and readable. Scrolling the code is a bit difficult unless really required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple decorated functions, and each function is given it's own independent `wrap_func` function object. These are independent.

If you must produce only one set of lines around multiple decorated functions calling each other, you'd need to keep a shared stack count; attach this information to the *decorator*, not the wrapper that the decorator returns:

```
def dec(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        stack_count = getattr(dec, '_stack_count', 0)
        if stack_count == 0:
            print(f'-- start of decorated functions -- {f.__name__}')
        dec._stack_count = stack_count + 1
        try:
            result = f(*args, **kwargs)
            if result: print(result)
        finally:
            dec._stack_count = stack_count
        if stack_count == 0:
            print(f'-- end of decorated functions -- {f.__name__}')
        # return result
    return wrapper
```

So the first call to the wrapper sets `dec._stack_count` to 1, after which any subsequent calls to wrappers will only further increment that number and nothing more is printed. On return, the counter is decremented again (the old, un-incremented value for that stack level is re-used), and only when that value is 0 again do we print again.

Note that I used `try...finally` to ensure the stack counter is decremented even if the decorated function raised an exception.

Demo:

```
>>> @dec
... def sum(a=1, b=1, times=1):
...     return (a + b) * times
...
>>> @dec
... def multi(a=2, b=3):
...     return sum(a, b=0, times=b)
...
>>> multi(2, 3)
-- start of decorated functions -- multi
6
-- end of decorated functions -- multi
>>> sum(2, 3)
-- start of decorated functions -- sum
5
-- end of decorated functions -- sum
```

Keeping track of a stack like that is really a context manager type of problem, so I'd further wrap this in such a context manager:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def print_outer(before, after):
    """Context manager that prints the before and after text only for the outermost call

    This is a reentrant context manager, and is not thread-safe.

    """
    outer = getattr(print_outer, '_is_outermost', True)
    if outer:
        print_outer._is_outermost = False
        print(before)
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        if outer:
            print_outer._is_outermost = True
            print(after)
```

then use this context manager in the decorator:

```
def dec(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        banners = (
            f'-- start of decorated functions -- {f.__name__}',
            f'-- end of decorated functions -- {f.__name__}'
        )
        with print_outer(*banners):
            result = f(*args, **kwargs)
            if result: print(result)
            # return result
    return wrapper
```

Comment: By the way what about thread safety in case `dec` is used in multiple threads?

Answer (score 1):

You can use some kind of global state lock which indicates whether one of the wrappers in the stack has printed already. This lock will be acquired by the outermost wrapper and prevents the inner ones from printing.

Code example:

```
lock = False

def dec(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        global lock
        if not lock:
            lock = True
            print('Start', f.__name__)
            result = f(*args, **kwargs)
            print('End', f.__name__)
            lock = False
        else:
            result = f(*args, **kwargs)
        return result
    return wrapper
```

Alternatively:

```
lock = False

def dec(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        global lock
        locked = lock
        if not locked:
            lock = True
            print('Start', f.__name__)
        result = f(*args, **kwargs)
        if not locked:
            lock = False
            print('End', f.__name__)
        return result
    return wrapper
```

Comment: A lock is *binary*, and so can't handle calling more than 2 levels deep.

Comment: @MartijnPieters As far as I understood the OP only wants to print the outermost function calling. So binary is sufficient as it will prevent all inner wrapped function calls from printing.

Comment: No, because you set the lock to false on the first return. You need a *counter* to track how deep you are in the stack.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I only set it to `False` if it hasn't been set before (and hence was acquired). Only the outermost function will set it to `False` *after* it evaluated all the innermost ones (which won't touch the lock since it has been set already). Actually we only need to know whether a decorator (the outermost) has been activated or not. That's something binary. Having a counter you also only check for `counter > 0` which is binary.

Comment: You also do the calling while holding the lock.

Comment: Right, it's the fact you state 'do the printing *and calling* here, that is then wrong. It is indeed a binary state (called or not, until the first call returns).

Comment: Hardly elegant now, with the two separate call sites, but now it at least works.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Admittedly I find your solution more elegant as well.